# Using the Android ProgressBar manually

Tags: android, android-progressbar

I don't need threads, I just want to increment the value of the progress bar manually by clicking a button.

Here's the XML code

```
<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/progressBar1"
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

And in the Java file I have

```
    ProgressBar pb;

    ...

    pb = (ProgressBar)findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);
    pb.setMax(100);
    pb.setProgress(0);
```

Now in a method that is called when a button is clicked, I want to increment the progress by one

```
public void increment(View view) {

    int progress = pb.getProgress();
    pb.setProgress(progress++);

}
```

This causes the program to crash. How can I control the ProgressBar from the Java program like this?

Comment: It'd be nice if you'd give your logcat errorlist or your stacktrace.

Comment: What is the error? Where does it crash?

Comment: It crashes at pb.setMax(100); with a null pointer exception.

Comment: Have you tried initializing your `ProgressBar pb` first? Something like `ProgressBar pb = new ProgessBar()`. (I believe you can set the max value in the xml file too)

Comment: because it is not found in you view hierarchy. Check that you call setContentView before calling findViewById

Comment: Looks like this line `pb = (ProgressBar)findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);` is assigning null to your `pb`.

Comment: Arcshade I have tried that, doesn't fix it.

njzk2, how can I get the 'view' parameter for setContentView to set the view hierarchy?

Comment: `myActivity.setContentView(R.layout.my_layout);` You need to set this somewhere at the start of the onCreate method.

Comment: Okay that fixed the first problem - the ProgressBar is displaying correctly, but now I can't access it from the increment() method. I can't call pb.getProgress();. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

2 options:

`final ProgressBar pb = (ProgressBar)findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);`

or

`private ProgressBar pb = null;` placed as global variable.

Comment: You should add the `private`. [In Java, what's the difference between public, default, protected, and private?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/215505/935627)